# Reading data with ADXL345 only when new data arrives

Tags: arduino, sensor, interrupts, accelerometer

I am using ADXL345 with Uno and ESP32. I am using ADXL345 with 50 Hz like this :

```
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345_DEVICE);
  Wire.write(0x2C);
  // Enable measurement
  Wire.write(0x09); //For low power 000x x pin set to 1  /1001 determine Hz
  Wire.endTransmission();
```

I want to share my sensor output ;

```
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.88,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.28}
{"x":-0.93,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.32}
{"x":-0.93,"y":-0.3,"z":-0.32}
```

As you can see, it prints same datas for 20ms. It refreshes every 20 milliseconds because of the data rate which is 50 Hz.

connections :

```
ADXL345 ARDUINO UNO
VCC     3.3V
GND     GND
SDA     SDA
SCL     SCL
INT1    PIN2
```

I solved it by adding delay(18) to loop. I don't want to use delay. I can use it millis but I want to do it by proper way. If new data came, I want to read the new data. I couldn't find on forum.

I read this on datasheet:

[image]

I though if I use these register, I can menage the proper way but interrupt didn't work too.
I opened a question 1 week ago and I couldn't find the answer. Maybe I need to change my approach to solve this situation. Is there any way to solve my problem ?

1 week ago post:

[electronics.stackexchangeforum](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/650635/adxl345-data-ready-interrupt-doesnt-work)

Comment: So isn't this a duplicate then? And the interrupt did work for three rounds?

Comment: I went through your code in the previous post. Why did you map all the interrupts to INT0 and not only the DATA_READY interrupt?

Comment: I don't see a wiring diagram anywhere.  Just to be sure, you *do* have additional, physical, wires connected for the interrupt signal(s) from the ADXL345 to the Uno/ESP32, in addition to the serial lines, right?  Fig 44 of the ADXL345 datasheet.

Comment: @Justme Kind of but I want to learn proper way, I think my way is not good since i don't get this work.

Comment: @PCBCrewEngineer I connected ADXL345's int0 to Arduino's pin2. I don't have any experience with these, I though I am doing the correct things.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen I am sorry, I am going to add the connections but my connections are correct.

Comment: @Tryingtogetsome Just because a pin on a chip is named interrupt, it does not mean you have to use interrupts. At least don't print from interrupts, that is something that should not bw done. Try reading the pin without interrupts first.

Comment: @Justme I can read the X,Y,Z values but It prints same data until 20ms. After this data is changing. I want to print data only when new data arrive. I can do this with sleep() or mlllis() ( I did) but that is not a good choice I guess.

Comment: @Tryingtogetsome Try reading the DATA_READY bit from INT_SOURCE register to see if the interrupts are being generated. If they are, try reading the data from the registers then.

Comment: Also, once you have the interrupt outputs connected and configured, do a reality check, and check these interrupt signals with an oscilloscope for activity and proper voltage levels.

Comment: @PCBCrew Engineer, I try to read INT_SOURCE and it returns "131".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the INT_SOURCE register returns 131 which translates to 0b10000011, it means that the DATA_READY is being set when new data is available.

You can modify your code to read this bit in the INT_SOURCE register and only read the axes data when this specific bit is set. Once you have read the axes data from the DATA registers, this bit will be cleared automatically according to pg.27 of [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl345.pdf).

[image: INTSOURCE register]

In this way, you'll be able to read the data only when new data is available and eliminate the need of using a separate interrupt pin which I think is not explicitly required in your case.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, just trying to understand... how is this effort any *less* than just reading the data?  If the point is to save cpu cycles, and increase efficiency (which it may not be the case here), then I see no real gain... You're still just *polling* the device.  Hardware interrupts could save precious overhead, with my limited understanding of this case.

Comment: @PCBCrew Engineer thank you but in code I wrote 0x2E register of INT_ENABLE  ```Wire.write(0x2E); ```
```Wire.write(0x80);``` but it returns 131. I read blue marked line, even If I wrote 0x80 , it is equal 0b10000011 instead of 0b10000000. I didn't understand that.

Comment: @Chris Knudsen I couldn't get the hardware interrupt work. My connections are correct but I have a problem with my code I guess.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen You are right but from what I understood, he only wants to read data from ADXL345. Yes, It's still polling but reading only one register would still save some cycles rather than reading six registers of data repeatedly.

Comment: @Tryingtogetsome You don't need to write anything to INT_ENABLE (0x2E) register. The datasheet states that INT_SOURCE (0x30) register works regardless of the INT_ENABLE (0x2E) register. You need to read data from INT_SOURCE (0x30) register only and check if DATA_READY (D7) bit is set or not.

Comment: @PCBCrewEngineer thank you. Do I need to connect this INT_SOURCE to interrupt and make a function to use interrupt? While is statement it is working really good but I really want to learn proper way to do it if I want to became an engineer.